# Confluence html macro ssl exception

Tags: html, ssl, macros, confluence

We are using the `html-include` `macro` for displaying content from an https resource. However, if we include the `macro` the following exception occurs:

> Error rendering macro 'html-include' : 
>           com.atlassian.renderer.v2.macro.MacroException: 
>           com.atlassian.confluence.macro.MacroExecutionException: 
>           javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
>           sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
>           sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
>           unable to find valid certification path to requested target

We don't know what to do for getting this to work. Can you please help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Cause**

The two instances communicating do not explicitly trust one another, even though they are using the same keystore.  The certificate the instances are using must be present in the truststore for server-to-server communication to work.

### **Resolution**

1. Follow the instructions in this document: [Connecting to LDAP or JIRA or Other Services via SSL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Connecting+to+LDAP+or+JIRA+or+Other+Services+via+SSL) if you are on JDK 1.5
2. Follow the instructions in this document: [keytool - Key and Certificate Management Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) if you are on JDK 1.6

**This will require a restart of all applications that have the parameter added.**